# Android RecyclerView Removing Item - 2 Animation Issues

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

When I click on a row in a vertical list `RecyclerView`, I call remove the item from the backing list, and call `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`. When `position == 0` the **move** animation is called, otherwise **remove** animation is called.

In both cases, after that animation is called, an **add** animation is called for all other visible items on the screen. This makes the remove animation look bad, because all other items flash while the remove animation is being run.

Anyone know what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using TwoWayView (github.com/lucasr/twoway-view). I've had too much trouble with it, and removing it seems to have fixed any trouble I was having, including this issue.

Filed an issue with the project on Github [here.](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/176)

Answer (score 0):

That does not make sense.

If you remove item at 0 (assuming it is visible and top item), there would be a "remove" for that item and "move" animation for all other visible views + one more (the new item to fill the new space but it comes with a move animation from below the list).

Can you post some code?

Comment: I was using `TwoWayView` (https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view). I've had too much trouble with it, and removing it seems to have fixed any trouble I was having, including this issue.

Comment: Glad it is resolved. TwoWayView is a great library, i think it would be nice to report those issues in its issue tracker.